# Android Google Analytics - 6 GET requests dispatched for single trackPageView

Tags: android, google-analytics

I have a fairly complex project that has many types of classes that I'm trying to track (fragments, activities, list fragments, mapactivites) etc. and I am trying to avoid using the easy tracker because I can't simply subclass that one class.

I have disabled all my tracking code in my various activities to attempt to pinpoint this and left just the code in my main Application subclass. I have deleted the app and reinstalled in the hopes of clearing anything that might be in a Google Analytics db file.

Here's the only Google Analytics related code I have:

```
    public class MyApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

    //Track app launch with version info
    PackageInfo pInfo = null;
    try {
        pInfo = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0);
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    String pageValue = "/app_launch/" + pInfo.versionName;

        tracker = GoogleAnalyticsTracker.getInstance();
        tracker.setDebug(true);
        tracker.startNewSession(getString(R.string.ga_web_property_id), this);      
        tracker.trackPageView(pageValue);
        tracker.dispatch();
        /etc...

    }
}
```

When I put a breakpoint and watch catlog this is what I get when dispatch() is called.

I'm totally confused why this is generating 6 tracking nearly identical GET requests to be dispatched. I've redacted my Google Analytics UA ID but otherwise this this represents the output of running the above onCreate a single time at app startup.

```
02-06 15:48:54.831: I/GoogleAnalyticsTracker(351): User-Agent: GoogleAnalytics/1.4.2 (Linux; U; Android 2.2; en-us; google_sdk Build/FRF91)
02-06 15:48:54.831: I/GoogleAnalyticsTracker(351): GET /__utm.gif?utmwv=4.8.1ma&utmn=764228238&utmcs=UTF-8&utmsr=480x800&utmul=en-US&utmp=%2Fapp_launch%2F1.0&utmac=UA-99999999-9&utmcc=__utma%3D1.35850864.1328029689.1328545392.1328571456.14%3B&utmhid=-719954799&utmht=1328571456916&utmqt=677896 HTTP/1.1
02-06 15:48:54.970: I/GoogleAnalyticsTracker(351): Host: www.google-analytics.com
02-06 15:48:54.970: I/GoogleAnalyticsTracker(351): User-Agent: GoogleAnalytics/1.4.2 (Linux; U; Android 2.2; en-us; google_sdk Build/FRF91)
02-06 15:48:54.970: I/GoogleAnalyticsTracker(351): GET /__utm.gif?utmwv=4.8.1ma&utmn=258792797&utmcs=UTF-8&utmsr=480x800&utmul=en-US&utmp=%2Fapp_launch%2F1.0&utmac=UA-99999999-9&utmcc=__utma%3D1.35850864.1328029689.1328571456.1328572132.15%3B&utmhid=968419361&utmht=1328572132799&utmqt=2154 HTTP/1.1
02-06 15:48:55.021: I/GoogleAnalyticsTracker(351): Host: www.google-analytics.com
02-06 15:48:55.021: I/GoogleAnalyticsTracker(351): User-Agent: GoogleAnalytics/1.4.2 (Linux; U; Android 2.2; en-us; google_sdk Build/FRF91)
02-06 15:48:55.021: I/GoogleAnalyticsTracker(351): GET /__utm.gif?utmwv=4.8.1ma&utmn=764228238&utmcs=UTF-8&utmsr=480x800&utmul=en-US&utmp=%2Fapp_launch%2F1.0&utmac=UA-99999999-9&utmcc=__utma%3D1.35850864.1328029689.1328545392.1328571456.14%3B&utmhid=-719954799&utmht=1328571456916&utmqt=678094 HTTP/1.1
02-06 15:48:55.100: I/GoogleAnalyticsTracker(351): Host: www.google-analytics.com
02-06 15:48:55.100: I/GoogleAnalyticsTracker(351): User-Agent: GoogleAnalytics/1.4.2 (Linux; U; Android 2.2; en-us; google_sdk Build/FRF91)
02-06 15:48:55.100: I/GoogleAnalyticsTracker(351): GET /__utm.gif?utmwv=4.8.1ma&utmn=764228238&utmcs=UTF-8&utmsr=480x800&utmul=en-US&utmp=%2Fapp_launch%2F1.0&utmac=UA-99999999-9&utmcc=__utma%3D1.35850864.1328029689.1328545392.1328571456.14%3B&utmhid=-719954799&utmht=1328571456916&utmqt=678175 HTTP/1.1
02-06 15:48:55.171: I/GoogleAnalyticsTracker(351): Host: www.google-analytics.com
02-06 15:48:55.171: I/GoogleAnalyticsTracker(351): User-Agent: GoogleAnalytics/1.4.2 (Linux; U; Android 2.2; en-us; google_sdk Build/FRF91)
02-06 15:48:55.171: I/GoogleAnalyticsTracker(351): GET /__utm.gif?utmwv=4.8.1ma&utmn=764228238&utmcs=UTF-8&utmsr=480x800&utmul=en-US&utmp=%2Fapp_launch%2F1.0&utmac=UA-99999999-9&utmcc=__utma%3D1.35850864.1328029689.1328545392.1328571456.14%3B&utmhid=-719954799&utmht=1328571456916&utmqt=678251 HTTP/1.1
02-06 15:48:55.251: I/GoogleAnalyticsTracker(351): Host: www.google-analytics.com
02-06 15:48:55.251: I/GoogleAnalyticsTracker(351): User-Agent: GoogleAnalytics/1.4.2 (Linux; U; Android 2.2; en-us; google_sdk Build/FRF91)
02-06 15:48:55.251: I/GoogleAnalyticsTracker(351): GET /__utm.gif?utmwv=4.8.1ma&utmn=764228238&utmcs=UTF-8&utmsr=480x800&utmul=en-US&utmp=%2Fapp_launch%2F1.0&utmac=UA-99999999-9&utmcc=__utma%3D1.35850864.1328029689.1328545392.1328571456.14%3B&utmhid=-719954799&utmht=1328571456916&utmqt=678324 HTTP/1.1
```